Can't do voxel_down_sample with Tensor PointCloud that has a user-defined property
I'm trying to do voxel_down_sample on an annotated point cloud. The annotations are simply a uint8 label defining a particular class of object.
If I omit the user defined property attached to each point, then the downsample works as expected.
Here's an example:
import open3d as o3d

device = o3d.core.Device("CPU:0")
pcd = o3d.t.geometry.PointCloud(device)
pcd.point.positions = o3d.core.Tensor([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]], device=device)
pcd.point.labels = o3d.core.Tensor([0,1,2], o3d.core.uint8, device=device)

pcd_ds = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=3)

If you comment out the pcd.point.labels = ... line, the downsample works, but if I try to include the labels, I get an error:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 6
      3 pcd.point.positions = o3d.core.Tensor([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]], device=device)
      4 pcd.point.labels = o3d.core.Tensor([0,1,2], o3d.core.uint8, device=device)
----> 6 pcd_ds = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=3)

RuntimeError: [Open3D Error] (void open3d::core::kernel::BinaryEW(const open3d::core::Tensor&, const open3d::core::Tensor&, open3d::core::Tensor&, open3d::core::kernel::BinaryEWOpCode)) /root/Open3D/cpp/open3d/core/kernel/BinaryEW.cpp:49: The broadcasted input shape [1, 1] does not match the output shape [1].

Is it possible to accomplish voxel downsampling with a PointCloud including a user defined property?
Versions:
Python v3.11
open3d v0.18

Try:
pcd.point.labels = o3d.core.Tensor([[0],[1],[2]], o3d.core.uint8, device=device)


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].
